# How to make React Material grid responsive?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I try to make this Grid bellow responsive but it's not working! :

```
 return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid
        container
        spacing={1}
      >
        <Grid
          item
          sm={3}
        >
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>item</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid
          item
          sm={9}
        >
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            (...)
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
```

Here you can see the results  :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The material grid is working like a row with 12 boxes, each box has a width of full width divide by 12.
and several layout. 
xs(extra small), sm(small), md(medium) and lg(large)

when you define 
xs={3} and xs={9}
means that when your layout is extra-small for eg: 120pixel width,

*the first component with xs={3} will occupied 3/12 * 120px = 30px*

*the second component with xs={9}, 9/12 * 120px = 90px*

so to make it responsive,
I assume you want the 'item' to occupied full width
you can make your component to

```
return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid
        container
        spacing={1}
      >
        <Grid
          item
          // changes here
          xs={12}
          sm={3}
        >
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>item</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid
          item
          // changes here
          xs={12}
          sm={9}
        >
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            (...)
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
```

xs={12} means when your layout is extra small, it will make you grid component to fill out the whole space(full width in this case)

you may try with other value, such as xs={6}
it will fill up half of the container.